# System.Serializable not working on a List<MyClass> in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

I'm in the process of creating a Loot system. I'm nearly at the end all I have left is to fill in the `DropTable` in the Inspector on my `Enemy` script. For some reason my `DropTable` script is serializing but, my `LootDrop` class is not. My classes are essentially  set up like so:

`DropTable` class:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class DropTable
{
 public List<LootDrop> loot = new List<LootDrop>();

 public Item GetDrop()
 {
    int roll = Random.Range(0, 101);
    int chanceSum = 0;
    foreach (LootDrop drop in loot)
    {
        chanceSum += drop.Chance;
        if (roll < chanceSum)
        {
            return ItemDatabase.Instance.GetItem(drop.itemSlug); //return the item here
        }
    }
        return null; //Didn't get anything from the roll
 }
}
```

`LootDrop` class:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class LootDrop
{
    public string itemSlug { get; set; }
    public int Chance { get; set; }
}
```

Essentially, my `DropTable` just contains a list of `LootDrop`. However, I cannot access the individual `LootDrop` instances inside of the `List<LootDrop>` from the inspector. All I am doing is creating a `public DropTable` variable on my `Enemy` script. I feel like I have done things similar to this before and had no problem. Am I doing something wrong here? I really wanted `DropTable` to be a separate class from my Enemy since the Enemy should not really care about the `GetDrop()` method. However, if that is the only way then I guess it'll have to do. Any help on this matter would be appreciated.

[image: inspector]

Comment: How do you initialize "loot" variable ?

Comment: @lucky I can't, that is the problem. I am trying to initialize it in the inspector. I can manipulate the list itself by adding entries but, it won't let me edit the entries themselves.

Comment: Can you show how instance of `DropTable` is declared and used and what a screenshot of what you currently see on the Inspector tab?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unity will serialize fields, not properties. Either switch to fields:

```c#
[Serializable]
public class LootDrop
{
    public int Chance;
}
```

Or use a serialized backing field:

```c#
[Serializable]
public class LootDrop
{
    public int Chance
    {
        get { return _chance; }
        set { _chance = value; }
    }

    [SerializeField]
    private int _chance;
}
```

Comment: I thought this was the issue too but OP claimed that `LootDrop` is not being serialized instead of saying that the variables in `LootDrop` are not being serialized.

Comment: @Programmer that was my mistake, I didn't even think of it being the variables that weren't serializing. I just assumed it was the whole class.

Comment: No problem at-all

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the `loot` variable before trying to add items.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class DropTable
{
    public List<LootDrop> Loot;

    public DropTable()
    {
        Loot = new List<LootDrop>();
    }
}
```

Also, be careful with name conventions.